# Using another field value as default in a solr function query

Tags: solr

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
/solr/select?q=_val_:query("{!dismax qf=text v='solr rocks'}", my_field)
```

But, specifying `my_field` as the default value throws the error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "my_field"
```

Additionally, these queries also fail:

```
/solr/select?q=_val_:query("{!dismax qf=text v='solr rocks'}", ceil(my_field))
/solr/select?q=_val_:query("{!dismax qf=text v='solr rocks'}", ceil(1.0))
```

Can we not specify another field or function as the default in function queries? Is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

I'm using Solr 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the code of the ValueSourceParser for QueryValueSource](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-core/3.1.0/org/apache/solr/search/ValueSourceParser.java#ValueSourceParser) (line 261), the 2nd argument of `query` can only be a float. So 3 or 4.5 would work, but `my_field` or `ceil(1.0)` which are `ValueSource`s instead of constants would not.

I don't know what your use case is, but would taking `max(query("{!dismax qf=text v='solr rocks'}"), my_field)` be good enough? (Provided that `my_field` has positive values, the result would only differ from what you are trying to do when the score of the query is lower than the value of `my_field`)

Otherwise, if you really need this feature, it should be fairly easy to implement your own function based on [QueryValueSource](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-core/3.1.0/org/apache/solr/search/function/QueryValueSource.java#QueryValueSource) in order to take a ValueSource as the 2nd argument instead of a float.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I voted it up, but I want to see if anyone has a workaround or another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I did find an alternate way to mimic the desired logic:

```
/solr/select?q=_val_:sum(query("{!dismax qf=text v='solr rocks'}"),product(map(query("{!dismax qf=text v='solr rocks'}",-1),0,100,0,1), my_field))
```

A little roundabout way to do it, but works fine.